# Mimic Context.getExternalFilesDir() prior to Android API Level 8?

Tags: android, directory, filesystems, android-context

Android API level 8 introduced the [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) method, providing a `File` object reference to an SD card path specific to your app.  I am wondering how to mimic this as low as API level 5.

I see there is a [`Context.getDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir(java.lang.String,+int)) method, but I can't tell from reading about it how this differs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternalits).  Here's an excerpt from that page that answers my exact question:

> If you're using API Level 7 or lower,
>   use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()), to
>   open a File representing the root of
>   the external storage. You should then
>   write your data in the following
>   directory:
>
> ```
> /Android/data/<package_name>/files/
> ```
>
> The `<package_name>` is your Java-style
>   package name, such as
>   "`com.example.android.app`". If the
>   user's device is running API Level 8
>   or greater and they uninstall your
>   application, this directory and all
>   its contents will be deleted.